# Violent/Non-Violent News Headlines from the Past

Tags: data-request, crime

Looking for data on news headline grouped by crime type: violent vs nonviolent; for 1993 and 2013 or 2014.

Comment: What region are you interested in?

Comment: Specifically, united States but worldwide would be a bonus